# Simple q: how to get data from Google form in email

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, notifications, add-on

I'm using a form to make a reservation. My goal is to have an automated email sent to the address entered in the form along with a specific data from the form (reservation date and time).

I'm working off this add-on:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms-add-on

The email is working, it will send the .html to the email address in the form after the form is submitted.

Now I'd like to get the 2 data fields from the form into the email (date and time).

Here are the snippets of code that I think are applicable, first the code.gs:

```
function sendRespondentNotification(response) {
 var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
 var settings = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
 var emailId = settings.getProperty('respondentEmailItemId');
 var emailItem = form.getItemById(parseInt(emailId));
 var respondentEmail = response.getResponseForItem(emailItem)
   .getResponse();
 if (respondentEmail) {
 var template =
    HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('RespondentNotification');
 template.paragraphs = settings.getProperty('responseText').split('\n');
 template.notice = NOTICE;
 var message = template.evaluate();
 MailApp.sendEmail(respondentEmail,
    settings.getProperty('responseSubject'),
    message.getContent(), {
      name: form.getTitle(),
        htmlBody: message.getContent()
    });
 }
}
```

Here is the .html for the email template:

```
  <html><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  <body>    
  <h1>Thank you for booking</h1>
  <p>Below are the details of your reservation:</p>
  <p>Date:</p>
  <p>Time:</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I've been trying something like `var date= form.getResponce(date)` in the script and `<?= date ?>` in the .html with no luck.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: to make this a valid question you need to include the actual code in question as well as an attempt at doing this if possible. this doesnt seem toxbe a question about coding but about how to use a program (specific add on)

Comment: edited to include code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the date into the template you have to set it on the variable `template` as is done for `paragraphs` and `NOTICE`

So after `template` is initialised and before it's evaluated you would put:

```
template.date = date;
```

or

```
template.date = form.getResponse(date);
```

Then, as you say, in the template (`RespondentNotification.html`) include the value as

```
<?= date ?>
```

ASIDE: You're not using `paragraphs` or `NOTICE` in your template so you may as well not set them on the `template` variable.